# how to zip an entire folder using python without add entire path to zip?

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip

I am suing python 2.7 in UBUNTU 16.04
i want to zip only the inner folder , not my working directory fir runing this script.
my code :

```
def zipdir(path, zip_file_name ):
    # ziph is zipfile handle
    ziph = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file))

    ziph.close()
```

create dir zip with all inner directories for example if I want to zip `/home/ubuntu/folder` it it wil zip `/home/ubutnu/folder` and not just folder and home have just ubuntu in it and Ubuntu has just folder in it . how to create zip for just folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [arcname](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) param.

**Ex:**

```
def zipdir(path, zip_file_name ):
    # ziph is zipfile handle
    ziph = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file), arcname=file)

    ziph.close()
```